# Adding Bootstrap or Grid Control to Your Existing Website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, gridcontrol

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com.

I want to ensure that no matter what the width of the page, the plugins and H1 never overlap the custom header.

Earlier in the week someone said '

'What I would suggest is you put your custom-header image and masthead header in 2 different rows of a grid control. That way you can restrict the rows to overlap.

Or, you can try implementing bootstrap in your website and you will not to handle resizing of browser as it will take care of all itself.'

Can someone tell me which idea would be easiest to implement on my existing website. I have very very little knowledge about either concept. I do not know how to even begin implementing either concept.

I think I have now installed Bootstrap on my website using the following code -

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css' );


wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
```

If I wanted to dedicated 12 columns just to the custom header then would I have to alter the code in customer-header.php or index.php?

Comment: hard to say, when we can't see your code

Comment: I have included more of my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258942/putting-custom-header-in-its-own-row.